# How does polymorphism work with undefined intermediate types in C#?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

In the following code, I would have expected calling `a.Generate(v)` would have resulted in calling `V.Visit(A a)`, since when Generate is called `this` is of type A. Hoewever, it appears that `this` is seen as being an `Inter` instead.

Is it possible to have the intended behaviour without explicitly implementing the (identical) method in both `A` and `B` and only on the shared base class? If so, how can it be acheived?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test {
    class Base {}
    class Inter: Base {
        public virtual void Generate(V v) {
            // `Visit(Base b)` and not `Visit(A a)` is called when calling
            // A.Generate(v). Why?
            v.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    class A: Inter {}
    class B: Inter {}

    class V {
        public void Visit(Base b) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        public void Visit(A a)    { Trace.WriteLine("a"); }
        public void Visit(B b)    { Trace.WriteLine("b"); }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            V v = new V();
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();

            a.Generate(v);
            b.Generate(v);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
It was suggested in the answers that the code above is not polymorphic. I would object to that. `V.Visit` is [polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Ad-hoc_polymorphism).

Comment: Hmmm... I think the only way to make that work is to implement Generate in both A and B.

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping there was another way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are expecting the call to `v.Visit(this)` to determine which overload of `Visit` to call based on the *run time types* of *both* `v` and `this`.

Languages which have that feature are called "double virtual dispatch" languages. (Or, if more than two things are considered they are called "multiple virtual dispatch" languages, or "multimethod" languages.)

C# is not a double-virtual dispatch language; it is a single-virtual dispatch language *when dispatch decisions are made at compile time*. That is, the decision of which overload to choose is made on the basis of the *runtime* type of the *receiver*, but the *compile-time* types of the *arguments*.

Now, in your case, C# does not use *single virtual dispatch* because the call to `Visit` is not even a virtual call in the first place! The fact that the call to `Generate` was a virtual call is completely irrelevant, and the fact that `Visit` is overloaded is also irrelevant. The dispatch to `Visit` is made *non-virtually*, so the dispatch logic is based entirely on the *compile-time* type of the receiver, `v`, and the argument `this`. Since the receiver is known to be of type `V` and the argument is known to be of type `Inter`, overload resolution must choose the best possible match *given only that information*. It cannot choose the versions of `Visit` that take `A` or `B` because those are *more derived* than the known argument type, `Inter`. It must choose the overload with the *less derived* formal parameter type, `Base`.

If you wish to achieve double-virtual dispatch in C#, there are two standard ways to do it. First, you can use `dynamic`; with `dynamic`, the analysis is performed at runtime using the runtime types.  Simply cast the receiver and the arguments to `dynamic` and the compiler will take care of it for you. That imposes a significant performance cost though.

The second standard way to do it is to use the **Visitor Pattern**, which you can find out about by searching the internet for it. I suspect based on the names of your methods that you are trying to implement the Visitor Pattern already; this is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Generate` method is defined in the `Iter` class. So when the `Generate` method is called, it passes a reference to an `Iter`.

If you want to pass `A` or `B` in, make `Generate` virtual and override it at the `A` and `B` level to pass in the properly cast value.

Comment: Overriding in `A` and `B` is exactly what I'd like to avoid, as the `Generate` method in both would be exactly the same.

Comment: Making `Generate` virtual doesn't change anything.

Comment: Isn't Generate() already declared virtual in the original question?

Comment: @StephenGross No, `Generate` wasn't virtual in the original question.

Comment: @Randolpho Ah! Another reason SO needs a more clearly visible edit history :)

Answer (score 2):

That is not polymorphic code, polymorphic code has dynamic binding which determines which method to call at runtime.  Both objects must have a similar base class with virtual methods to do this dynamic binding.  Right now your binding is static and is determined at compile time.

Comment: V.Visit is polymorphioc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad-hoc_polymorphism

Comment: `V.Visit` is not polymorphic. That's called operation overloading. Your link even tells you that.

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect exactly?

```
public void Visit(Base b) { Trace.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name);  }
```

Somehow, the compiler compiles one version of the code for v.Visit(this). It can't compile different versions for each call instance according to the real tpye of the argument passed.

In a polymorphic design, Inter and each of its derived classes are responsible for doing "personal" stuff.

```
public void Visit(Base b) { b.VisitedBy(v);  }
```

where `VisitedBy()` is a virtual function.

Comment: I expect the code in `Main()` to never call `V.Visit(Base b)`.